# How will windows 10 update work?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

Yesterday, I wake up, turn on my computer and realize my pc hard drive is dead. I had a backup, went get a new hard drive and I installed it. But, I can't find my recovery disk and I can't download Windows 7 from the internet. I want to know, if I would install Ubuntu on my computer until Windows 10 is released, will I be able to get the free upgrade to Windows 10 without Windows 7 currently installed? I have my Windows 7 product id and also, if it change something, my pc came preinstalled with Windows 7.

Comment: No, you have to have an eligible Windows OS installed for the free upgrade to install. What brand of PC is it?

Comment: [Can I do a clean install using the Free upgrade?
No, it will require that you are running a previous qualifying version and start the upgrade from within the qualifying version. You can initiate a clean install after completing the Upgrade.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/frequently-asked-questions-windows-10/5c0b9368-a9e8-4238-b1e4-45f4b7ed2fb9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-iso

--and download the Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft.

Look for the "English US" link if that is where you are.

Don't forget to copy and paste the Product Key, lower down on that page.

Follow the rest of the instructions on the page, including burning the ISO to a DVD disk, which you will then boot over.

Read the whole page and make sure you are aware of what to expect. Running this installation will take a LONG TIME, so be patient.

NOTE: you MUST register as a "Windows Insider", using a Microsoft account as the user, in order to qualify to run this Windows 10 installation. On or around July 29th, you will be invited to update to the final release. As long as you remain a Insider and keep the Microsoft account you created you can run Windows 10 as long as you wish. You will create that account near the end of the installation...

Comment: Re: MoaB: Please go to URL:  http://www.zdnet.com/article/with-a-nod-and-a-wink-microsoft-gives-away-windows-10-to-anyone-who-asks/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I finally found a way to download windows 7 from a mirror